# POST JSON with JSON attribute to java API rest

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jackson

I have a java API (rest) that accepts a JSON as body request.
I need to map the body to a java class, but one of the JSON attributes is a JSON itself, and I cannot predict its structure.

For example, this is the resource:

```
@POST
public void paymentInfo(PaymentInfoEntity paymentInfoEntity)
throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
   ...
}
```

This is a JSON example:

```
{
   progressive: 123,
   params: { [another valid JSON node] }
}
```

This is how I'd like the entity:

```
public class PaymentInfoEntity {
    public Integer progressive;
    public JsonNode params;
}
```

With this configuration, I have this error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, problem: abstract
>   types can only be instantiated with additional type information

The same error occour if I declare `BaseJsonNode params` instead of `JsonNode params`.

If I declare, instead, a `Object params`, it works.
How can I then parse a JSON from this? In this case `params.toString()` is the form `{key1=stringvalue1, key2=stringvalue2}` instead of `{key1: "stringvalue1", key2: "stringvalue2"}`.

Which is the best option to achieve my goal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonNode is an abstract type. Try to use BaseJsonNode
or java.util.Map

Comment: As I wrote, I tried also BaseJsonNode, with same result. Map<String, Object> seems to works, thank you. I then get a JSON Object using new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(paymentInfoEntity.getParams()).